# How to write to tmp file or stream an image object up to s3 in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, amazon-s3

The code below resizes my image.  But I am not sure how to write it out to a temp file or blob so I can upload it to s3.

```
  origImage = MiniMagick::Image.open(myPhoto.tempfile.path)
  origImage.resize "200x200"
  thumbKey = "tiny-#{key}"

  obj = bucket.objects[thumbKey].write(:file => origImage.write("tiny.jpg"))
```

I can upload the original file just fine to s3 with the below command:

```
obj = bucket.objects[key].write('data')
obj.write(:file => myPhoto.tempfile)
```

I think I want to create a temp file, read the image file into it and upload that:

```
  thumbFile = Tempfile.new('temp')
  thumbFile.write(origImage.read)
  obj = bucket.objects[thumbKey].write(:file => thumbFile)
```

but the origImage class doesn't have a read command.

**UPDATE:**  I was reading the source code and found this out about the write command

```
# Writes the temporary file out to either a file location (by passing in a String) or by
# passing in a Stream that you can #write(chunk) to repeatedly
#
# @param output_to [IOStream, String] Some kind of stream object that needs to be read or a file path as a String
# @return [IOStream, Boolean] If you pass in a file location [String] then you get a success boolean. If its a stream, you get it back.
# Writes the temporary image that we are using for processing to the output path
```

And the s3 api docs say you can stream the content using a code block like:

```
obj.write do |buffer, bytes|
 # writing fewer than the requested number of bytes to the buffer
 # will cause write to stop yielding to the block
end
```

How do I change my code so

origImage.write(s3stream here)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html

**UPDATE 2**

This code successfully uploads the thumbnail file to s3.  But I would still love to know how to stream it up.  It would be much more efficient I think.

```
  #resize image and upload a thumbnail
  smallImage = MiniMagick::Image.open(myPhoto.tempfile.path)
  smallImage.resize "200x200"
  thumbKey = "tiny-#{key}"
  newFile = Tempfile.new("tempimage")
  smallImage.write(newFile.path)
  obj = bucket.objects[thumbKey].write('data')
  obj.write(:file => newFile)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your follow-up updates, they helped me get my code up and running!  Did you ever end up figuring out how to stream it directly to S3 vs writing the temp file?  Just curious.

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing. I couldn't see a way to get a stream out of of MiniMagick either.

Comment: @Jondlm  I ended up skipping the streaming to locally and followed this process to just stream the file straight from the client to s3. http://blog.tcs.de/post-file-to-s3-using-node/  this example uses node, but I got it working with ruby as well.

Answer (score 0):

`smallImage.to_blob` ?

below code copy from https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick/blob/master/lib/mini_magick.rb

```
    # Gives you raw image data back
    # @return [String] binary string
    def to_blob
      f = File.new @path
      f.binmode
      f.read
    ensure
      f.close if f
    end
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem? The gem offers direct compatibility to s3 and works great.